# How to convert a JSON String into an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I am facing an issue while converting an NSString to NSArray.

My string is :

```
["Default", "Discipleship", "Faith", "Family", "Hope", 
 "Life Building", "Love", "Missions", "Relationships"]
```

What i want to do is get the elements(Default,Discipleship etc.) out of this string and put them into an NSArray.

I have tried a lot but couldn't get it done, please help
Any help would be great , thanks in advance

Comment: So you know that it is JSON but you did not find NSJSONSerialization in the documentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First you convert your string to NSData:

```
NSString* str = @"[\"Default\",\"Discipleship\",\"Faith\",\"Family\",\"Hope\",\"Life Building\",\"Love\",\"Missions\",\"Relationships\"]";
NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then, you use:

```
NSError *e;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&e];
```

The object array contains the elements of the JSON text.

Comment: This is probably to correct answer. (But you have to escape the quotes in the first line, otherwise it will not compile.)

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I just copied and pasted the question's string. I'll edit to make it right.

Comment: This is still wrong. Use: [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&e]; if you want it to work. The last line of this looks good but on closer inspection is just rubbish -> [NSJSONSerialization data options:nil error:&e] is WRONG;

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *list = @"Default,Discipleship,Faith,Family,Hope,Life Building,Love,Missions,Relationships";

NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

**EDIT**:
 Please refer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

for further understanding on NSString.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,first trim unwanted charecters and after that conver string into array.

```
NSString * strippedNumber = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\"]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [val length])];
NSArray *array = [strippedNumber componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sathvik for reply, but again i got something inappropriate as an Array: array i got is : array is ::(
    "[Default",
    Discipleship,
    Faith,
    Family,
    Hope,
    "Life Building",
    Love,
    Missions,
    "Relationships]"
)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this and for that need to add jsonkit and import josnkit.h in your class

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString]
JKParseOptionFlags options = JKParseOptionComments | JKParseOptionUnicodeNewlines;
NSArray *responsArray=[responseString objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:options error:nil];
```